# PyCharm looking for firefox when the browser I set is chrome

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I am getting this error

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

even though i set it to chrome

**my code:**

```py
chromedriver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
```

What could be the reason why PyCharm is looking for firefox browser? Because the code above is working on my other project.

I am using macOS and i have already set the default browser to chrome in system preferences and also in pycharm

Comment: is `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` a file on your machine?